# I want to pre-fill an input of type IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, asp.net-core, web

I'm doing an Edit page for some products that have an ImagePath property. When I create the product, I use an input of type IFormFile to download the image in the /img/products folder of the website and it works perfectly fine. Here it is for context:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProduct(AdminCreateProductVM vm)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(vm);

    bool productAlreadyExists = _context.Products.Any(u => u.SKU == vm.SKU);

    if (productAlreadyExists)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Un produit avec le même SKU existe déjà.");
        return View(vm);
    }

    if (vm.Image is not null && vm.Image.Length > 0)
    {
        var webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        var filePath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "img/products", vm.SKU! + ".jpg");

        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await vm.Image.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Veuillez sélectionner une image.");
        return View(vm);
    }

    var product = new Product()
    {
        SKU = vm.SKU,
        Name = vm.Name,
        Brand = vm.Brand,
        Model = vm.Model,
        ImagePath = "~/img/products/" + vm.SKU + ".jpg",
        WeightInGrams = vm.WeightInGrams,
        Size = vm.Size,
        Quantity = vm.Quantity,
        RetailPrice = vm.RetailPrice,
        DiscountedPrice = vm.DiscountedPrice,
        ShortDescription = vm.ShortDescription,
        FullDescription = vm.FullDescription,
        PublicationDate = (DateTime?)DateTime.Now,
        LastUpdated = (DateTime?)DateTime.Now,
        IsArchived = false
    };

    _context.Products.Add(product);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(ManageProduct));
}
```

The problem is when I want to modify the product, I want to fill the IFormFile input with the image that is currently associated with the product by default, but leave the possibiliy to change it by uploading a new one. I've tried multiple things so that the ViewModel contains an IFormFile when loading the new page, and it all didn't work. The code that I have currenlty (see bellow) create the IFormFile object with everything needed property-wise, but when the page is loading, the input isn't pre-filled.

```
public IActionResult EditProduct(Guid id)
{
    ViewBag.Id = id;

    var toEdit = _context.Products.Find(id);

    if (toEdit is null)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(id));

    IFormFile? toEditImage = null;
    string toEditFullImagePath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + toEdit.ImagePath![1..];

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(toEditFullImagePath))
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(toEditFullImagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(toEditFullImagePath);

            var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            if (!provider.TryGetContentType(fileName, out var contentType))
            {
                contentType = "application/octet-stream"; // Utilisez un type MIME par défaut si l'extension n'est pas reconnue.
            }

            var headers = new HeaderDictionary
            {
                ["Content-Disposition"] = new StringValues("form-data; name=\"Image\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""),
                ["Content-Type"] = new StringValues(contentType)
            };

            toEditImage = new FormFile(fileStream, 0, fileStream.Length, fileName, fileName)
            {
                Headers = headers
            };
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "L'image du produit n'a pas été trouvée.");
    }

    var vm = new AdminEditProductVM
    {
        SKU = toEdit.SKU,
        Name = toEdit.Name,
        Brand = toEdit.Brand,
        Model = toEdit.Model,
        Image = toEditImage,
        WeightInGrams = toEdit.WeightInGrams,
        Size = toEdit.Size,
        Quantity = toEdit.Quantity,
        RetailPrice = toEdit.RetailPrice,
        DiscountedPrice = toEdit.DiscountedPrice,
        ShortDescription = toEdit.ShortDescription,
        FullDescription = toEdit.FullDescription
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

If you need any code from the html input or the ViewModel, let me know. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot programmatically set default chosen file in browser for security reasons. It would be a serious security flaw. The user must manually select a file through the file input field.

You can set a hidden input for `ImagePath`, when you do not want to change the product image, you can do not select a file and then post to the backend to judge the file is null or not. If the file input is not null, you can do something like `CreateProduct` did, to update the `ImagePath` value. If it is null, just invoke database update query.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I'll probably make it so that you have to check a checkbox to say that you want to modify the image and make the input appear if the checkbox is checked.